# Magento 2: add custom font to theme

Tags: magento2, theme, fonts

I'm using a custom theme on my Magento 2.3.2.
I would like to add a custom font that is on my folder.

Since the official guide that i found on magento's site wasn't working for me, I've tracked down where the font in .body was set.

I've found the file **lib/web/css/source/lib/variables/_typography.less**

This is the piece of code that decides the font

```
@font-family__sans-serif: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
```

Now, I've tried to change those names and I can see changes happening on the site, problem is I can't figure out how to set the path to my custom font. I've tried a few things but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1):

Please Follow the Below steps

**Step 1** Please Upload your fonts file woff and woff2 in this

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/web/fonts/fontdirectory

File Path

**Step 2**
Please include font family in this

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/web/css/source/_typography.less

file Path

For Example

```
& when (@media-common = true) {
    .lib-font-face(
        @family-name: @font-family__base,
        @font-path: '@{baseDir}fonts/fontdirectory/<<font_name>>',
        @font-weight: 300,
        @font-style: normal,
        @font-display: swap
    );
}
```

**Step 3** Please add the Below code on the same file (_typography.less)

```
@font-family__base`: '<<font_name>>';
```

**Please execute static content deploy command**

Comment: I am creating custom theme , shall i use same file?

Comment: Yes, @zus. Please try and let me know in case of any issue

Comment: i just put all my fonts into fonts folder, then what i need to do?

Comment: before that can i get help here https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/328503/57334

Comment: Now you can follow steps 2 and 3. In Step 2 you can include the font path. if you have uploaded or put the font on direct font directory then set this *@{baseDir}fonts/<<font_name>>* font path in Step 2 and last you can add this *@font-family__base`: '<<font_name>>';* line in same file. please sent font file name instead of this <<font_name>>. For example the uploaded file name is opensens.woff then path is like this *@font-path: '@{baseDir}fonts/opensens'*

Comment: font post https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/328498/57334

Comment: pls guide me...

Comment: Ok, @sus. I will know you in detail. Please let me know the font file type. for example woff and TTF etc...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117755/discussion-between-saneer-ladani-and-zus).

Comment: otf font https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117755/discussion-between-saneer-ladani-and-zus

Comment: I am getting error like woff2 which i never use, any help thanks. see chat

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to add fonts.

First is you can use direct google fonts link. Below is the file path to add direct links in the xml file.

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

Below is the example.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,700;0,900;1,300;1,400;1,700;1,900" src_type="url" />
```

Below has the second way to add fonts.

1. Please Upload your fonts woff and woff2 in below path.

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/web/fonts/

2. After adding fonts in respected folder you have to include that fonts in css file like below :

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/web/css/style.css

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    src: url('../fonts/proxima_nova_semibold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/proxima_nova_semibold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/proxima_nova_semibold-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../fonts/proxima_nova_semibold-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Also you can use fonts like below after inlucding in css.

```
font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif';
```

Let me know still you facing any issue.

Thanks