# M2 - How to include my custom font in custom theme?

Tags: magento2.3.4, custom-theme, fonts

How to apply **adobe laca font**, https://fonts.adobe.com/fonts/laca

[image]

How to apply?

I am created custom theme inherit from blank theme.

Custom font declaration :

app\design\frontend\Myrwd\mytheme\web\css\source\ _typography.less

```
& when (@media-common = true) {
    .lib-font-face(
    @family-name: @font-family__base,
    @font-path: '@{baseDir}fonts/Laca-Regular',
    @font-weight: 400,
    @font-style: normal,
    @font-display: swap
    );
    }
    @font-family__base: 'laca, sans-serif' !important;
```

Answer (score 0):

Upload fonts to theme is not enough you must import in less file in your theme

Comment: pls see my updated post, i have declared in typography.less

Comment: Seem you include wrong name `font-family__base`. Instead that you should use 
`font-family__base: Laca'

Answer (score 0):

Here the below example of Roboto font you can follow the same with your custom theme for custom font:-

First add fonts in `app\design\frontend\Myrwd\mytheme\web\fonts\roboto` folder like below

[image]

`app\design\frontend\Myrwd\mytheme\web\css\source\ _typography.less`

```
@font-face {
    font-family: @font-family-name__base;
    src: url('@{baseDir}fonts/roboto/Roboto-Medium.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('@{baseDir}fonts/roboto/Roboto-Medium.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: 500;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: @font-family-name__base;
    src: url('@{baseDir}fonts/roboto/Roboto-Bold.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('@{baseDir}fonts/roboto/Roboto-Bold.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: @font-family-name__base;
    src: url('@{baseDir}fonts/roboto/Roboto-Italic.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('@{baseDir}fonts/roboto/Roboto-Italic.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: @font-family-name__base;
    src: url('@{baseDir}fonts/roboto/Roboto-Light.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('@{baseDir}fonts/roboto/Roboto-Light.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: @font-family-name__base;
    src: url('@{baseDir}fonts/roboto/Roboto-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('@{baseDir}fonts/roboto/Roboto-Regular.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: @font-family-name__base;
    src: url('@{baseDir}fonts/roboto/Roboto-LightItalic.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('@{baseDir}fonts/roboto/Roboto-LightItalic.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: @font-family-name__base;
    src: url('@{baseDir}fonts/roboto/Roboto-Black.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('@{baseDir}fonts/roboto/Roboto-Black.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: 900;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: @font-family-name__base;
    src: url("@{baseDir}fonts/roboto/Roboto-Thin.woff") format("woff"),
    url("@{baseDir}fonts/roboto/Roboto-Thin.woff2") format("woff2");
    font-weight: 100;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Add below variable in `app\design\frontend\Myrwd\mytheme\web\css\source\_variables.less` file.

```
@font-family-name__base: 'Roboto';
@font-family__base: @font-family-name__base, @font-family__sans-serif;
```

Comment: How to solve this error https://justpaste.it/8spjo

Comment: I have created _typography.less under web/css/source and include into _extend.less under web/css/source.

Comment: FYI - I have created _variables.less and common.less under web/css/source/components for my global variables purpose,

Comment: Global variable steps by using https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/328886/57334

Comment: Shall i move _variables.less to web/css/source?

Comment: remove `components` folder and `common.less` file and add your custom variable in `_variables.less` at this path `app\design\frontend\Myrwd\mytheme\web\css\source\_variables.less`

Comment: I just removed my components and common.less file, actually i have assign h1 tag h1 {
    color: @h1-main-color;
} in common.less, now which file i need to assign global values?

Comment: FYI in this post said declare global variables in _variables.less under web/css/components and assign in common.less under web/css/source/components  https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/328886/57334 How to assign global variable values?

Comment: I hope my points clear, any doubts?